# Sync SharePoint Online list to database (Mysql)

Tags: sharepoint-online, database

Is it possible to sync a sharepoint online list to a database like Mysql hosted on azure?  If not, what is an alternative solution? Is a custom connector possible?

[image]
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Office 365 SharePoint Online BCS with [Azure Database for MySQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/) or use the [third-party connector.](https://www.layer2solutions.com/solutions/general-data-integration/mysql-codeless-data-integration-synchronization)

Since I could't find any documents about connecting Azure MySQL with SharePoint, here is the article about Azure SQL database connection for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28286.office-365-sharepoint-online-bcs-with-azure-sql-server-database.aspx

More information:

https://www.peters.com/blog/exposing-sql-data-sharepoint-online/